# mysql_real_escape() parameter warning

Tags: php, mysql

Hi guys I'm creating my own DB class but I have come across a problem. Here is my DB class

```
class Mysql {

    var $connect;

    function ConnectDB() {
        $this->connect = mysql_connect(SERVER, USER, PASS) or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $this->connect) or die(mysql_error());
    }

    function IsLogin() {
        if (isset($_SESSION['id']) && isset($_SESSION['rollno'])) {
            $id     = $_SESSION['id'];
            $rollno = $_SESSION['rollno'];
            $query  = "SELECT student_rollno FROM" . TABLE_USER . " WHERE student_email='$id'";
            $result = mysql_query($query, $this->connect);
            $row    = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            if (!$result || mysql_num_rows($query) < 1 || $row['student_rollno'] != $rollno) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}

;
$database = new Mysql;
```

db class consist of these two and few other functions... the `IsLogin()` function is working. The problem is that I have included this `class.page` in another script but when I use `mysql_real_escape_string($string, $database->connectDB());` it says...

> Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be
>   resource, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\input_validate.php on
>   line 25

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ). If you're starting to get familiarized with OOP, I recommend you check PDO out.

Comment: Are you ever calling `Mysql::ConnectDB`...? I also don't see where you're using `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Comment: Thank you Madara Uchilha for suggesting the new approach..

Comment: lol. you need to use `mysql_connect()` and `mysql_select_db()` before you call `mysq_real_escape_string()`

Answer (score 0):

```
function ConnectDB() {
    $this->connect = mysql_connect(SERVER, USER, PASS) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $this->connect) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

should be like this:

```
function ConnectDB() {
    $this->connect = mysql_connect(SERVER, USER, PASS);
    if(!$this->connect){
        die(mysql_error());
    }
    $selectdb = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $this->connect);
    if(!$selectdb){
        die(mysql_error());
    }
    return $this->connect;
}
```

Basically you are missing return statement, so method does not return db but null.

Please consider moving to mysqli or PDO, since mysql_* are no longer maintained.